# How to properly upload a local file to a server using mobaXterm?

Tags: linux, mobaxterm

I'm trying to upload a file from my local desktop to a server and I'm using this command:

```
scp myFile.txt cooluser@192.168.10.102:/opt/nicescada/web
```

following the structure: scp filename user@ip:/remotePath.

But I get "Permission Denied". I tried using sudo , but I get the same message. I'm being able to download from the server to my local machine, so I assume I have all permissions needed.

What can be wrong in that line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case your `/desired/path` on your destination machine has write access only for root, and if you have an account on your destination machine with sudo privileges (super user privileges by prefixing a `sudo` to your command), you could also do it the following way:

## Option 1 based on scp:

1. copy the file to a location on your destination machine where you have write access like `/tmp`:

   ```
   scp file user@destinationMachine:/tmp
   ```
2. Login to your destination machine with:

   ```
   ssh user@destinationMachine
   ```
3. Move the file to your `/desired/path` with:

   ```
   sudo mv /tmp/file /desired/path
   ```

In case you have a passwordless sudo setup you could also combine step 2. and 3. to

```
ssh user@destination sudo mv /tmp/file /desired/path
```

## Option 2 based on rsync

Another maybe even simpler option would be to use `rsync`:

```
rsync -e "ssh -tt" --rsync-path="sudo rsync" file user@destinationMachine:/desired/path
```

with `-e "ssh -tt"` added to run sudo without having a tty.

Answer (score 2):

Try and specify the full destination path:

```
scp myFile.txt cooluser@192.168.10.102:/opt/nicescada/web/myFile.txt
```

Of course, double-check `cooluser` has the right to *write* (not just read) in that folder: 755, not 644 for the `web` parent folder.

Comment: buddy, how can I check If cooluser has permissions to write? I'm new to linux, very very new.

Comment: @JulioRodriguez open an ssh interactive shell session on the remote machine: `ssh cooluser@192.168.10.102`. From that shell, type `cd /opt/nicescada/web/`, then `ls -alrth`. Check the line '.': (current folder), copy that line in the comments.

Comment: Buddy, I got this:

drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   24 Aug 13  2019 protected
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2.3K Aug 13  2019 startupTemplate.htm
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  264 Aug 13  2019 manuales
drwxr-xr-x.  7 root root  138 Aug 13  2019 WEB-INF
drwxr-xr-x. 34 root root 4.0K Aug 13  2019 resources
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  724 Aug 13  2019 index.jsp
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   25 Aug 13  2019 robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   88 Aug 13  2019 exception
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root root 4.0K Aug 13  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x. 15 root root 4.0K Aug 13  2019 js

Comment: @JulioRodriguez That means it is owned by `root`. Nobody but `root` can write in it. If you can ask an admin to change that web folder to cooluser (`sudo chown cooluser /opt/nicescada/web`), that would help.